# MSG stream Id calculation

Tags: mapi, msg

I'm trying to calculate the stream name for the named property part of an MSG file, specifically string named properties. The [MSG file format specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912.aspx) [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202960.aspx) that the ID is generated as follows:

> `Stream ID = 0x100m ((ID XOR (GUID index << 1 | 1)) MOD 0x1f`

Where the ID value is the CRC-32 for the "Unicode name identifier". I'm also confident that `0x100m` is actually `0x1000`.

This somehow maps `'x-mailer'` to `0x100f` when the GUID index is 3. The value for ID is 0x894e50ff (since it is stored in another location), but how does `'x-mailer'` get converted to that value?

(These are the properties stored under `"__nameid_version1.0"`, partly inside the `"__substg1.0_00040102"` stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/os_exchangeprotocols/thread/a2db4ec9-a561-4e39-a3ca-ca25e53051bd?prof=required&ppud=4) from a Microsoft Engineer:

> Hi Luke,
>
> Sorry it took so long to get back to
>   you on this.  I verified the CRC-32
>   calculation and it indeed results in a
>   value of 0xff504e89 for the string
>   'x-mailer'.  Two things that you need
>   to consider:
>
> 1. make sure you are calculating CRC for 'x-mailer' as a UNICODE string. 
>      ASCII will give you a different
>      result.
> 2. make sure you are using the algorithm specified by MS-OXRTFCP
>      sections 3.1.3.2 and 3.1.4 including
>      using the precalculated lookup table
>      and the corresponding algorithm
>      pseudocode.
>
> If you follow these, you will get the
>   proper result.
>
> Let me know if you are able to get
>   this working.
>
> Regards, Tom Jebo Senior Support
>   Escalation Engineer Microsoft DS
>   Protocol Team